# QWidget update events but no visual update

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtableview

Using Qt4.8 on a Mint Linux 12, I implemented a simple window containing a `QTableView` to show contents of a model. The model data is continually updated (log messages) and the `dataChanged()` signal is emitted on a regular basis (i.e. every 100ms).

The problem I see is stuttering visual updates on the table.

I installed an event filter on the window that counts `updateRequest`-type events, which should trigger a widget repaint (also on child widgets, i.e. the `tableView`). These come in with an average time of ~170ms between them and a standard deviation of ~90ms (which is rather large, I guess). However, the perceived visual update rate is only two or three times a second and I wonder why. It seems that not all `updateRequest` events trigger a widget repaint or that the window system swallows visual updates.

As a second test, I forced the window to update itself by calling `repaint` or `update` every 100ms. Using `repaint`, I saw a corresponding increase in `updateRequest`-type events and a decrease of the standard deviation of the gaps; with `update`, the number did not increase. However, there was only a moderate increase of perceived update rate in both cases.

Also: Is there a good method to measure how often a widget is actually really repainted without having to overload its `paintEvent` handler? Maybe something from `QTest`?

---

**Update:** I extended my event filter to also catch `paintEvent`-type events. There are only a one-digit number of those versus > 1000 `updateRequest`-type events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instrument the event dispatcher's `aboutToBlock()` and `awake()` signals, and measure time between them using a `QElapsedTimer`. The instance of the event dispatcher for the current thread is returned by the static `QAbstractEventDispatcher::instance()`.

If the event loop sleeps for a very small fraction of your time measurement window, it means there's too much stuff going on in the GUI thread. You can keep a count of how long the event loop slept, say, during the last second. If it's below 10%, you can expect slow updates and whatnot. Remember that update events are queued with `Qt::LowEventPriority`. They will be preempted by standard queued signals and almost all other events.

Comment: Good idea! I'm currently on a tight schedule project-wise, so it will take a couple of days to test this. I think this should give me a good overview of the load, but I actually counted the updateRequest events that reach my widget and those come much closer (on average, mind) than the perceived update rate.

Comment: The counting is fine, but it doesn't tell you anything about the underlying problem. It just tells you there is a problem, and well, you can obviously notice it without writing a single line of code :)

Answer (score 0):

`QApplication::compressEvent` discards `QEvent::UpdateRequest`, if there is already one unprocessed. Thus even repaint(s) can return immediately without painting, if the event is discarded. You can check, if your `updateRequest` events are discarded by overwriting `compressEvent`.

Comment: I know about compression, but isn't this done in the main event loop/QApplication somewhere? I thought that if an updateRequest reaches a widget, this should already be done.

Comment: You are right, the compression is done in the EventLoop. I misunderstood, where you count the events. And yes, if the event reaches the widget, the compression is already done. So, ignore my answer.